# Show that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ is not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, integral-domain

Why is $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ not an integral domain?

My professor laid out a proof in class today. Some clarification would be very helpful.

> **Consider**: $$(i \otimes i)^2 = -1 \otimes -1 = 1 \otimes 1$$
>
> This implies that:  $$(i \otimes i - 1 \otimes 1)(i \otimes i + 1 \otimes 1) = 0$$
>   But neither factors are 0, therefore $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ is not an integral domain. $\blacksquare$

Can anyone show me why $(i \otimes i)^2 = -1 \otimes -1 = 1 \otimes 1$ and how this implies that the product is equal to 0?

Comment: How is multiplication in $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ defined?  What is $(z_1 \otimes z_2)(w_1 \otimes w_2)$?

Comment: The multiplication is defined by: $(z_1w_1 \otimes z_2w_2)$ @MatthewLeingang

Comment: You got it!  But $i^2=-1$ so $(i\otimes i)^2 = (-1) \otimes (-1)$.  But $-1$ is real so you can slide it over to the other side of the $\otimes$, where it combines with the other $-1$ to become $1$.  Hence $(i\otimes i)^2=1\otimes 1$.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewLeingang :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that

$$\begin{align}
(i\otimes i)^2 &=i^2\otimes i^2\\
&=(-1)\otimes (-1)\\
&=(-1)(-1)\otimes 1\\
&=1\otimes 1
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
(i\otimes i-1\otimes 1)(i\otimes i+1\otimes 1)&=(i\otimes i)(i\otimes i)+(i\otimes i)(1\otimes 1)\\
&-(1\otimes 1)(i\otimes i)-(1\otimes 1)^2\\
&=(i\otimes i)^2-(1\otimes 1)=0.
\end{align}$$